# Inserting a values with condition

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2005

I want to insert a table with where condition

Table1 column Name - ID, Name, Dept, Rank

Query

```
Insert into table1 values('1', 'Raja' 'IT', 'True') where Rank <> 'False'
```

Need Query Help

Comment: Use an UPDATE statement instead of INSERT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into table 1 select '1', 'raja', 'it', 'true' from SomePlaceWhereRankExists where rank <> 'false'
```

It's not clear where 'Rank' is coming from in your pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're attempting something along the lines of:

```
IF @rank <> 'false'
  Insert into table1 values('1', 'Raja' 'IT', 'True')
```

You're not particularly clear about your goal however. Are you trying to update existing records or insert new ones? If you're inserting new ones, what are you trying to achieve using a where clause?